# HDR video publishing

Tags: winapi, colors, ms-media-foundation, direct2d, hdr

I'm relative new to HDR and I'm trying to understand the color transfer functions. The idea is to produce a YouTube-compatible HDR video.

So I manage to create a Direct2D surface with `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT` and use `GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat` bitmaps and my primitives have a full color range as well.

I can convert these bitmaps to 10-10-10-2 DWORD (10-bit) with WIC (from `GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat` to `GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102`) and use the NVidia NvEnc H.265 with `NV_ENC_HEVC_PROFILE_MAIN10_GUID` and `NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_ABGR10` buffers.

So far, so good. My app produces a 10-bit YUV video which plays correctly in Windows and also can be correctly loaded with Media Foundation in my editor later on.

The troubles begin when I specify in the NVEnc color transfers. As far as I understand, the color transfer modes describe the way to translate color values into light for HDR displays.

When I put the PG or HLG specs to NvEnc:

```
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.videoSignalTypePresentFlag = 1;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.videoFormat = NV_ENC_VUI_VIDEO_FORMAT_UNSPECIFIED;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.videoFullRangeFlag = 0;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.colourDescriptionPresentFlag = 1;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.colourPrimaries = NV_ENC_VUI_COLOR_PRIMARIES_BT2020;
ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.transferCharacteristics = NV_ENC_VUI_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_SMPTE2084;                            ne.encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.hevcVUIParameters.colourMatrix = NV_ENC_VUI_MATRIX_COEFFS_BT2020_NCL;
```

the result video is recognized in YouTube as HDR but it plays badly, colors are heavily distorted (same in Windows Player).

The question is, how do I need to pre-process my RGB10 input in order to be correctly transferred with PQ or HLG?

I was suggested [OpenColorIO](https://opencolorio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/colorspace.html), I'm not very much sure how to proceed from now on.

Reading stuff in https://www.lightillusion.com/what_is_hdr.html, there's a PQ table:

```
10,000 nits = 1023
5,000 nits = 948
4,000 nits = 924
2,000 nits = 847
1,000 nits = 769
400 nits = 668
100 nits = 519
0 nits = 0
```

Does that mean that I have to transform the color's linear luminance to these levels somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to specify a transfer function if you didn't use it initially? Otherwise from Direct2D you can use the "Color management effect" with D2D1_GAMMA1_G2084 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/color-management (I don't believe there's any HLG native support in Windows)

Comment: Because Youtube wont accept a video without it. I will take a look at the color management.

Comment: Can't you just pass NV_ENC_VUI_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_BT2020_12

Comment: Then youtube wont see it as HDR. It only wants PQ or HLG.

Comment: Have you tried it? this is legit HDR

Comment: I just pushed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CattAbrFtPg with NV_ENC_VUI_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_BT2020_12  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FGlHDJlHp4 with NV_ENC_VUI_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_BT2020_10, it takes a while to process them as HDR, let's see if it does.

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't identify them as HDR (see [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7126552?hl=en))

Comment: I've seen that, but it's unclear as they say "if you're grading, then use PQ or HLG", which could mean that grading is not mandatory

Comment: @SimonMourier If I I don't use PQ and I don't insert the PQ metadata in the MP4, it will no way accept it as HDR. 
`To be processed, HDR videos must be tagged with the correct:
Transfer function (PQ or HLG)
Color primaries (Rec. 2020)
Matrix (Rec. 2020 non-constant luminance)`